# Why I can't process Kafka message?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

I have a generic `Message<>` message sent via Kafka Template `(kafkaTemplate.send(topic, message))`, but on consumer side I have such an error on processing sent message:

```
there is no default constructor available in 'org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage'
```

How can I add it and why should I do it? I thought that is should work out of the box?

```
public void publishEvent(Event createdEvent) {
    String topic = structureTask.getType();

    Message<TaskCreatedEvent> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(
            TaskCreatedEvent.builder().taskId(createdEvent.getId()).build()).build();

    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, Message<?>>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topic, message);
    future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, Message<?>> result) {
            log.debug("Sent {} with offset={}", message, result.getRecordMetadata().offset());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
            log.debug("Unable to send {} due to: {}", message, ex.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you give code detail? :)

Comment: Sure, 
Message<Event> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(Event.builder().id(event.getId()).build()).build();

ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, Message<?>>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, message);

Comment: as exception: `Event` DTO not having default constructor. Can y give Event code?

Comment: Because to send message to kafka, kafkatemplate will convert generic class via reflection also required `Event` having default constructor.  Do You try to add default constructor to resolve the problem?

Comment: Could you update your question with code samples?

Comment: @NguaCon added sample code. I have no arg constructor in event, but how can I add it to GenericMessage? And there is event more it has MessageHeaders. Maybe it's not right to use spring integration GenericMessage here?

Comment: @kamaci  Added sample code. Thank you!

Comment: Can you give code of `Event` ?